# is there a list of keyboard shortcuts for the "Videos" app?

Tags: shortcut-keys, video, totem

I'm using 14.04 ubuntu with the default video player called "Videos" version 3.10.1 (which seems to be "Totem" re-branded with an even *less* search engine-friendly name.)

I know keyboard shortcuts work, as I've accidentally found a few (example: "Q" quits the entire program without a warning prompt), but I can't seem to find a comprehensive list either in the online or built-in help. Can anyone point me toward one?

Known so far:

<kbd>q</kbd> quit

<kbd>Left arrow</kbd>skip backward 15 sec

<kbd>Right arrow</kbd> skip ahead 1 minute

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd> skip backwards 5 sec

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd> skip ahead 15 sec

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Totem [man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/totem.1.html):

```
KEYBINDINGS
       Global keybindings for Totem:

       a                 cycle between aspect ratios
       p                 toggle between play and pause
       Esc               exit full screen mode
       f                 toggle full screen
       h                 toggle display of on-screen controls
       0                 resize window to 50% original size
       1                 resize window to 100% original size
       2                 resize window to 200% original size
       r                 zoom in the video
       t                 zoom out the video
       d                 start and stop the telestrator (drawing) mode
       e                 erase the drawing
       Left-arrow        skip back 15 seconds
       Right-arrow       skip forward 60 seconds
       Shift+Left-arrow  skip back 5 seconds
       Shift+Right-arrow skip forward 15 seconds
       Ctrl+Left-arrow   skip back 3 minutes
       Ctrl+Right arrow  skip forward 10 minutes
       Up-arrow          increase volume by 8%
       Down-arrow        decrease volume by 8%
       b                 jump back to previous chapter/movie in playlist
       n                 jump to next chapter/movie in playlist
       q                 quit
       Ctrl+E            eject the playing optical media
       Ctrl+O            open a new file
       Ctrl+L            open a new URI
       F9                toggle display of the playlist
       m                 show the DVD menu
       c                 show the DVD chapter menu
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how I missed that. Surely search engines index these pages but even **keybindings  totem -warcraft** has a bad S/N ratio

Answer (score 1):

You can also find explanations to keyboard shortcuts in Totems help menu:

It is accessible by:

- clicking **Help** > **Content**
- pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>